# Issue in changing orientation in android

Tags: java, android, android-orientation

Just making a test application that should display a log message on changing orientation, but when i change orientation using ctrl + f11, there is nothing shown in the logcat.
what is the issue in the coding

A Part From Manifest

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.orientationtest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
```

A part from Java

```
package com.example.orientationtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        Log.d("error", " orientation changes");
    }

}
```

Comment: Everything looks fine.....add a breakpoint on onConfigurationChanged and check whether it is getting called or not when you are changing the orientation...

Comment: its not getting called

Comment: try changing to this:
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"

Comment: try changing to this:
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize".
also the doumentation on activity: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html
, mention that in some cases, onConfigurationChanged , won;t be called: "If a configuration change involves any that you do not handle, however, the activity will still be restarted and onConfigurationChanged(Configuration) will not be called."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this if target api 13 and above

```
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"
```

or

```
   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout"
```

for lower than 13 ..... this will help you... :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `configChanges` is not a good idea if you only want to know if the screen rotated. It basically means that you plan to handle the whole rotation change by yourself in the code.

If you don't plan to do this, just check what is the current rotation when your `Activity` is created:

```
int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
```

Then just do whatever you want using this check:

```
if(currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
    //if landscape
} else {
    //if portrait
}
```

This way you don't need to touch your manifest file and you let your app manage the configuration changes by itself.

You can keep the previous orientation used in the activity saved instance if you need to compare the previous and the current one.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you prevented the android from changing its orientation

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

that line of code is preventing it to configuration change and that why your not getting any response..